# Android: How to create new Database tables dynamically by the users themselves?

Tags: android, database, oncreate

I am trying to figure out a way to dynamically create new tables in my DB upon user request. My current DB class works with the following code. I am trying to figure out how to change this to be able to dynamically create new tables. One of my ideas was to use this code and first create a table with onCreate that will hold the names of the future Tables. From there, when the user enters a new table, I will add that table to the current table that will hold the table names, and from there I will select it and use to to actually create the table with that specific name. I am not sure if that will actually work but it is something that I just thought of and wanted to see what you guys think.

```
private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    /* Constructor */
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_FRONT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_BACK + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i'm in favor of your idea specifically. I think it's best to have the foundation that you're essentially trying to make an SQLite String *first*. It's important to have some intermediate data holders before the eventual table creation as well.

Personally, i'd make a form and an `Object` that can read through everything (Table name, column numbers, etc.) on the form and output that one string that you need. then if need be, you can save the entire `String` in to `SharedPrefs` or `SQLite` however you prefer.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean and agree with it. I can handle the data entry etc... but my problem is with what I do with the onCreate method. Since the App may end up with several different tables for the duration of it's life. So do I have to update the onCreate every time a new table is added? That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: oh i see, i don't think you even have to worry about `onCreate` at all. `onCreate` isn't the only opportunity to create tables. you can do it so long as the you can input the `execSQL` command. but what you do have to worry about is version number. if if you make a new table or changes to one, you're gonna need to increase the version number to show changes and `onUpgrade` will be called, that's what you need to worry about.

Comment: Do you think it will be better to simply create two tables. first will be the table with all the different "tables" and the second table will simply be all the entries and the entries will have a column to specify their connection with the entry in the first column? Somehow to simplify the creation of tables, and make it where I would only need two and connect the two? Then when I need to collect every value for that specific table name, I will load it into an arrayList or something of that sort.

Comment: i think i see where you're going now. perhaps have one column in one table as an identifier(ex. `"table_name::column name"`) or something, then put entries in other columns. i have to say, if you really can't think any other design that requires dynamically making tables like this, then you could go for it. personally, i'd do it in the way i assumed if i found a good way to manage the database version number.

Comment: mango, thanks for your help. I think I will stick with the two tables design as my data will be pretty much identical in type and function. Thanks a lot for sticking with this thread!